# Centos 6.x root no longer can chown or chmod

Tags: linux

I am receiving the following error when changing perms on `/var/lib/mysql`

```
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/asterisk': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/ib_logfile0': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/test2': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/kk': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/test': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/ib_logfile1': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/mysql': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/asteriskcdrdb': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `mysql/wh': Operation not permitted
```

How do I fix this? Before you post I have looked there are no immutable bits set
I am logged in as root so why can I not change permissions I need my database back.

Comment: Is the filesystem read-only?

Comment: Can you type the command `mount` and provide its output?

Answer (score 3):

A number of different things could be causing this.  I would check all of the following:

- Is the file system read-only?  Check by calling `mount` or looking at `/proc/self/mounts`?
- Is the file system a local file system?  Network file systems often limit root.
- Are you truly root, or has your set of capabilities been limited?  Check by running `capsh --print`.
- Are you running selinux?  Check if `getenforce` returns `Enforcing`.
- If you are running selinux, are you confined?  Check `id -Z`, which should return something like `unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023` if you are not confined.
- Are you sure there are no weird attributes?  Make sure `lsattr` doesn't return any weird bits.